# Divider color in ListFragment

Tags: android

I am trying to change the color of the divider in my list frament. I have this line

```
getListView().setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
```

in my `onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)`. IT makes the divider line vanish. Anyone know why this is? And how I can make the divider change color.

P.S: i know this is not a big problem, but it is driving me nuts and id like to change color if possible.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this -

```
getListView().setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
getListView().setDividerHeight(1);
```

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks man. I should have taught of that one my self.

Answer (score 4):

In the method `onActivityCreated()` of your `ListFragment` add this in this order:

```
    getListView().setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.BLUE));
    getListView().setDividerHeight(1);
```